# Restart the Universe expansion?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, biology

Is there anything that could restart the universe expansion?

Basically a black whole or something else entirely different?  It seems to me that, once the Universe stops expanding, the human life would be non-existent.

Comment: I've deleted a number of off-topic comments and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments are meant to be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarifications on their parent posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to our current understanding, [the universe is expanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe), it appears to have always been expanding, and [the expansion appears to be accelerating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerating_expansion_of_the_universe).

The expansion (nor contraction) of the universe has no effect on humanity. The effect is so small on our scale that it's unnoticeable. The local gravitational attraction of our galaxy and Sun negate any local effect of expansion or contraction; space will expand, but gravity will still hold our galaxy and nearby galaxies together for quite some time.

Eventually expansion will be happening so fast that all other galaxies will be moving away from us, even in our [local group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Group). In [about 2,000,000,000,000 years all other galaxies will be accelerating away so quickly we will no longer be able to see them](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/20571/how-long-will-it-be-until-the-nearby-groups-of-galaxies-are-receding-at-speeds-f), they will be moving away at the speed of light. Even then the only effect on what counts as humanity 2 trillion years from now is they will have no evidence of a universe outside their galaxy.

See also

- [How Will The Universe End?](https://youtu.be/Qg4vb-KH5F4) PBS Space Time

Comment: If the universe is expanding what will happen to human life?

Comment: The universe has been expanding for the entire history of human life.

Comment: Olbers' paradox ?

Comment: @William Human life will go about its business totally unaffected and evolve into something else. The time scales are so different. Humans have been around maybe 100,000 years. Life, Earth, and the Sun have been around a few billion years. Cosmological expansion won't have a noticeable effect for hundreds of billions of years. [This timeline may help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_of_an_expanding_universe).